# Difference between, your argument was clear from the beginning or start,

Tags: sentence-meaning

Your argument was clear to us from the **start/beginning** there's no need to labour the point.

Which one is better suited or how do we differentiate between the start and beginning?

Comment: There is no discernable difference in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument was clear to us from the start/beginning; there's no need to labor the point.

There's no difference in meaning. They mean the same thing.  However, beginning is more formal than start.